# Trying to insert a NULL date on form submission but getting 00:00

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to allow for NULL dates (for permanent type bans) on a form insert, but if the field is left blank it inserts `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

The `BannedMembers` table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE BannedMembers
(
 BanID         INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 MemberID      INT NOT NULL ,
 WarningSent   BIT NOT NULL ,
 BannedDate    DATETIME NOT NULL ,
 BanDuration   DATETIME NULL ,

 PRIMARY KEY  (BanID),
 FOREIGN KEY (MemberID)
    REFERENCES Members(MemberID)
);
```

I want to enable permanent bans by leaving the duration as NULL, my HTML/PHP script (abridged):

```
<form method="post" name="banmember_form" id="banmember_form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    Banned Until? (Leave empty for permanent)
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="banmember_duration" id="banmember_duration" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
    <button type="submit" name="addbannedmember_submit" id="addbannedmember_submit">Add</button>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["addbannedmember_submit"]))
{
    //Check if the duration is empty (for permanent bans)
    if (empty($_POST["banmember_duration"]))
    {
        $banDuration = NULL ;
    }
    else
    {
        $banDuration = $_POST["banmember_duration"];
    }
    $addBannedMemberSql = "INSERT INTO BannedMembers(MemberID, BannedDate, 
    BanDuration)
    VALUES (".$_POST["banmember_name"]."',NOW(),'$banDuration') ";
    $conn->exec($addBannedMemberSql);
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
    }
?>
```

From what I read, and what I was able to find out, the NULL above is being stored as `''` so when it inserts it just defaults back to `00:00...etc`. I couldn't find an answer on how to fix it, many ideas said to remove the `''`s while others said to include them, I tried `({$banDuration})` in my `INSERT` but same issue.

I don't fully understand prepared statements since I a very new to this, and was hopeful there was a way of storing NULL as a blank entity to pass to the DB if it is left blank by the user.

Comment: What's the type of your field in database? Probably the field has a default value.

Comment: As above in my SQL it was BanDuration DATETIME NULL I altered the column to BanDuration   DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL the same issue persists.

Comment: _“I don't fully understand prepared statements”_ - right now you are not really using them at all, because you are still inserting data values directly into the query. And `'$banDuration'` will result in `'NULL'`, that is not the NULL value, that is a _text literal_ containing the characters `NULL`.

Comment: Is `$banDuration` definitely being set to null? Try die($addBannedMemberSql);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by changing my Variable:

From: `$banDuration = NULL ;` to `$banDuration = "NULL" ;`

And my INSERT statement From:

`VALUES (".$_POST["banmember_name"]."',NOW(),'$banDuration') ";`

To

`VALUES ('".$_POST["banmember_name"]."',NOW(), (".$banDuration.")) ";`

Result:

```
|ID  |  Banned Date         |   Banned Until|
|502 |  2018-10-16 20:03:52 |   NULL        |
```

Not sure if this is the best work around, but it resolved my issue.

Comment: Or you could choose not to insert `$banDuration` it when its empty

Answer (score 0):

Problem with the 'NULL' string you try to save.
You can use something like that:

```
if(isset($_POST["addbannedmember_submit"])) {
    //Check if the duration is empty (for permanent bans)
    if (empty($_POST["banmember_duration"])) {
        $banDuration = NULL ;
    } else {
        $banDuration = "'" . $_POST["banmember_duration"] . "'";
    }
    $addBannedMemberSql = "INSERT INTO BannedMembers(MemberID, BannedDate, BanDuration)
    VALUES (".$_POST["banmember_name"]."',NOW(),$banDuration) ";
    $conn->exec($addBannedMemberSql);
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
}
```